# Do the Western countries sell arms or military equipment to China or vice versa?

Tags: united-states, china

Any kind of equipment relating to defense?

Comment: Chinese firearms (eg. Norinco) are inexpensive and well-made. They are prohibited from import to the US but are sold in many other countries. Mexico has apparently bought their 105mm howitzers.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

assuming that you are talking about mainland china, not taiwan.

they are under an arms embargo right now. so sales of weapon systems would be illegal.

but it is much murkier on sales of technology, especially dual-use technology.

before the embargo was put in place, china was a buyer of western weapons. I think they have a fleet of black hawk helicopters.

edit: I forgot to mention that western countries sold many diesel and gas turbine engines currently used on chinese naval vessels. China also developed its horwitzers, both ultra-light weight and self-propelled, with help from some western countries.

Comment: Danny, please reference your claims, the embargo first, then the black hawk helicopters.  Or put these as comments.

Answer (score -1):

The US military buys parts from China. As recent as 2014 Obama prevented a law passing that would block purchase of China products: ([thenewamerican.com - Obama Pentagon waived ban on chinese parts in US weapons](http://www.thenewamerican.com/usnews/congress/item/17358-obama-pentagon-waived-ban-on-chinese-parts-in-u-s-weapons)). You and I have a household budget and buy made in China stuff from Walmart to save money. The Pentagon also has a budget (a little larger at $600B+) and will buy stuff from China too. Somethings may not even be made in America anymore.

I can see Trump trying to change that after someone tells him. For example find out the most popular computer chips bought from China and setup plants in America to manufacture them. Then coerce Canada and other major trading parties to buy American rather than Chinese, possibly with export subsidies.

Comment: fake chips out of china have been cited as issues for some weapons programs. but that's not what this question is about.

Answer (score -2):

The Chinese aircraft carrier [*Liaoning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_aircraft_carrier_Liaoning) is actually a former Soviet aircraft carrier that was sold to China by Russia. Russia actually frequently has [Arms deals](https://www.ft.com/content/90b1ada2-a18e-11e6-86d5-4e36b35c3550) with China.

Besides that as far as I know most of the European nations and the US to not have arms deals with China for strategic/political reasons.

Comment: Is Russia part of the 'West'?

Comment: @anonymous Yes. Russia is a westernized nation. The fact that it is physically to the east is not relevant. Westernization is more of a question of culture than geography. Also keep in mind that political center of Russia is in Europe.

Comment: I am not going to involve in debate. Coz, I don't have enough time for this.

Comment: > The Chinese aircraft carrier Liaoning is actually a former Soviet aircraft carrier that was sold to China by Russia. it depends on your definition of "russia". technically, the seller is Ukraine. The carrier was built in Ukraine as well. the sale took place after the break-up of the USSR.

Comment: > most of the European nations and the US to not have arms deals with China for strategic/political reasons: there is an arms embargo. China was rumored to be a potential buyer for the assault ship that the french was building for the russians during the ukraine crisis.

Comment: @dannyf Russia got the money, ergo russia is the seller. Ukraine being part of the former soviet union for better or worse has little to do with it. Also the reason for the arms embargo is political/strategic. Plus not all nations abide by the embargo

Comment: > Russia got the money, ergo russia is the seller. how did russia got the money? the sale took place after the break-up - ukraine couldn't continue the build and had no reason to own the carrier after the break-up.

Comment: > Also the reason for the arms embargo is political/strategic. the embargo was triggered by a certain event in 1989.

Comment: @dannyf Any you believe that its been around for the past 20 years just for that one reason in a vacuum?